# How to get value of a character in a string c++?

Tags: c++

Let's say I had a string. How would I be able to get the value of the first character of that string?

For example:

```
string str = "apple";
```

I want to get the first character of `str` which would return `97`.

Comment: `the first character of str which would return 1` What?

Comment: Because `char test = 'a'` is 1?

Comment: Because `sizeof(test) == 1`, or because _a_ is the first letter of the alphabet?

Comment: Oh wait. `a` actually has an integer value of `97`. My bad.

Comment: I was talking about this `(int)test`. Sorry.

Comment: So you're looking to retrieve the `char` representation of a character in a `std::string`?

Comment: @Tas Yes. How would one do that?

Comment: Well, accessing separate characters in your string can be done with `str[i]` or `str.at(i)` or using iterators (`i` is the position). Cast that to `int` if you want the integer value.

Comment: It's that simple? Wow.

Comment: Yes, a string is an array of characters, right? You can handle it the way you handle a basic array.

Comment: All of the above is the long way of saying [you need a **good book**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?s=1|32.8232) on C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the ASCII-Value/Code of the specific character.

```
string str = "apple";
char c1;
char c2;

c1 = str[0];
c2 = str.at(0);

std::cout << static_cast<int>(c1) << std::endl;
std::cout << static_cast<int>(c2) << std::endl;
```